# Downloading data from a particular Workbook of a URL with an Excel File

Tags: python, excel

I don't know how to convert the 5th Workbook of my [CSV](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls) File into a Dataframe. My current code is as follows, however I just want the data from the 5th Workbook and I was wondering how to do this:

```
import csv
import urllib2
import StringIO 
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls'

df = pd.ExcelFile(os.path.basename(url))
print df
```

Thank You

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @TharinduKumara I get the Error: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'uknom05_mdaily.xls'`. Does it just mean I haven't save the Excel File locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the xlrd using

```
apt-get install python-xlrd
```

And then try this code.

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd 

url = 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls'
socket = urllib2.urlopen(url)

xd = pd.ExcelFile(socket)
df = xd.parse(xd.sheet_names[-1], header=None)

print df
```

Comment: Thank You. I had installed `xlrd` but I didn't realize I had to `import` it.